# Time complexity of INSERTION SORT when A is nearly sorted and k is a constant

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Let's say A is an array of integers that is nearly sorted
if each element has at most k positions
away from its correct position. What is the time complexity
of InsertionSort when A is nearly sorted and k is a
constant?

Comment: How do you compute the time complexity of insertion sort without the "nearly sorted" constraint? What happens to that computation when each element is at most k positions away?

Comment: Perhaps if you can't figure it out for general k, try working through k=0, then k=1, then k=2 and so on until you get the idea.